# Using Eclipse to edit post-merge META-INF files merged by Maven shade plugin

Tags: eclipse, maven, maven-shade-plugin

I'm working on a [project called vertx-bigapp-skeleton](https://github.com/marcelalburg/vertx-bigapp-skeleton) to make the Vert.x deployment easier.

For that, I decided to create a file called `META-INF/vertx.verticle` in the verticles (Maven submodules of the [example project](https://github.com/marcelalburg/vertx-bigapp-skeleton/tree/master/examples)).

If I compile and run the project with Maven (`mvn clean package && java -jar server/target/application.jar`) everything works fine and the Maven shade plugin merge's the `vertx.verticle` file correctly.

I work with Eclipse and if I run the example server artifact it just finds the `vertx.verticle` file from the healh verticle.

It is possible to merge this `META-INF/vertx.verticles` file in eclipse too, so that I can develop and debug in Eclipse?

The Loader for the vertx.verticles files can be found here: https://github.com/marcelalburg/vertx-bigapp-skeleton/blob/master/src/main/java/com/weeaar/vertxwebconfig/service/ServiceLoader.java

Thanks for your help

Comment: Open a bug at eclipse m2e to handle this...but i think this will help cause maven-shade will in package phase which is usually not running within eclipse...

Comment: Is there any other method? Because spring boot using almost the same (with spring.verticles) and this works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

i used

```
public static final String FACTORIES_VERTICLES_LOCATION = "META-INF/vertx.verticle";
input = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream( FACTORIES_VERTICLES_LOCATION );
```

but this just found one of the files

if i switched to

```
Enumeration<URL> urls = ClassLoader.getSystemResources( FACTORIES_VERTICLES_LOCATION );
```

everything works.

thanks marcel